# Solve double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates

$$
\int_0^2 \int_0^{4-x^2} \frac{xe^{2y}}{4-y} \, dy\, dx
$$

I'm stuck with this problem. I think I should change it so I integrate with respect to $dx \, dy$ but I'm not sure. Any help? Thanks

Comment: change the order to dxdy .your bounds will change .maybe that work

Comment: I integrated with respect to x and got ((4-y)e^(2y))/2. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, integrate first with respect to $x$, where $x$ goes from $0$ to $\sqrt{4-y}$. That will cancel the nasty $4-y$ at the bottom.

Comment: Ok I will try that, but how did you get the limit of integration with respect to x? you just solved for x? (y=4-x^2)

Comment: Yes, I sort of solved for $x$. But first I drew a picture, $y=4-x^2$ is a familiar downward facing parabola. We are integrating over the first-quadrant part of the parabola. So $x$ goes from $0$ to $y=4-x^2$, or equivalently from $0$ to $\sqrt{4-y}$. But the picture comes first, then the manipulation.

Comment: Thank you @André Nicolas. Did you get the same answer? (e^8 - 1) /4

Comment: You are welcome. After a short while we are integrating $(1/2)e^{2y}$, get exactly your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\int_0^4\int_0^{\sqrt{4-y}}\frac{xe^{2y}}{4-y}\,dx \,dy$$

Does it ring a bell?

Comment: after integrating with respect to x and then y I get (e^8)/8 is this correct?

Comment: No. It is $\frac14(e^8-1)$

Comment: @Paul : So you hand him the bottom line answer and ask if it rings a bell?  Why should it ring a bell? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I cannot help telling @Kevin94 the answer>

Comment: I got 1/8 *e^2y *(9-2y) evaluate from 0 to 4.  Is this right?

Comment: No. It is $\frac12 e^{2y}$.

Comment: @Paul is the integral with respect to x =  ((x^2)e^(2y))/4-y ?

Comment: It is $\frac12(x^2)e^{2y}/4-y$

Comment: I finally got it . Thank for your help. So the answer is (e^8  - 1) /4 ?

Comment: Yes, it is. You are welcome!